# Prevent edit in arduino ide to prevent cheating

Tags: arduino

I'm developing web based game based on Wemos d1 Mini, and for users to enter their wifi address so that it connect to WiFi, I have to provide the arduino sketch.
To avoid cheating, is there way to disable section of code to be edited or lock some variables so that it cannot be changed in arduino IDE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see WiFiManager library

Comment: You don't want them to have the source code?   Don't give it to them.  What do you think is uploaded onto the board?

Comment: The reason why I must give the code is because i want it to be open sourced as well. I guess its impossible given the user has access to the source code

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can provide other means of entering configuration data.

ESP can emulate EPROM, or you can read from Serial/LittleFS/SPIFFS before you establish a WiFi connection.

If the user has access to your source code, there's no "cheating", that's improving your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to not have your user edit the sketch to enter WIFI credentials.

To name the most obvious

1. have them entered via serial interface
2. have them provided via a file on a SD card for example
3. have them entered using some kind of user interface
4. use WPS

about the anti-cheat stuff I suggest you do some further research how things can be approached. this  cannot be answered given the provided information

Answer (score 0):

You start by creating an access point with set SSID/password users should receive from you and you also create a web server to accept user's credentials for their WiFi network. You can do that using a GET string or create a page with fields.

Once credentials entered by the user you store it in flash or EEPROM or whatever facilities exists, and you reboot the device.

When device starts it checks the credentials and tries to connect, if it fails you go back to the access point and web server stage.